# How search a datum in ArrayList<StringBuilder> with indexOf

Tags: java, search, arraylist, stringbuilder, indexof

How search a datum in ArrayList with indexOf

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> state = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
state.add(new StringBuilder("A"));
state.add(new StringBuilder("B"));
state.add(new StringBuilder("C"));
state.add(new StringBuilder("D"));
System.out.println(state.indexOf(new StringBuilder("B"))); //Out: -1
```

Comment: StringBuilder doesn't override equals so you can't.

Comment: Use String instead of  StringBuilder

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an `ArrayList` of `StringBuilder`objects.

As `StringBuilder` is used for building strings, and not as actually `String`s , you can't use `indexOf(s)`, as the whole object itself should be equal to the one you are comparing so that it returns `true`.

In order to solve this problem, you should build the `String` however you want with the `StringBuilder`, and make an ArrayList of already-built `String`s only, like this:

```
ArrayList<String> state = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("A")
//Do whatever you want to a
state.add(a.toString());
state.add(b.toString());
state.add(c.toString());
state.add(d.toString());
.....
System.out.println(state.indexOf("B")); //Out: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it searches by reference and you want to search by the contents of the string builder.

```
boolean there = state.stream() // use streams API
                     .anyMatch(sb -> sb.toString().equals("B")); // check string equals

System.out.println(there); // print if it's there
```